# Usage of TSQL string_split in DAX

Tags: powerbi, dax, ssas, tabular

I have 2 tables in SSAS / Power BI:

Table1:

```
| ValueName| ValueKey |
|:----     |:------:  |
| abc      | 1,2,3    |
```

Table2:

```
| ID   | ValueKey | Value  |
|:---- |:------: |:------: |
| ID1  | 1       | 87,8    |
| ID2  | 85      | 14      |
| ID3  | 90      | 95,8    |
| ID4  | 3       | 13,4    |
```

I need to retrieve  (in temp table, later make calculations over this temp table) ID, Value and only those rows, which have ValueKey 1 or 2 or 3.

I need to do it with DAX. In SQL we have for such situation STING_SPLIT function. Is there some way how can I achive this with DAX? My ValueKey column (table1) is comma separated text and ValueKey (table2) column is INT.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you use PowerQuery as well? Or does the solution needs to be solely DAX?

Comment: I have SSAS tabular model where I can do the changes in VS - PBI connected as Live connection.

Comment: You can abuse the `PATH` functions for this after replacing `,` with `|`, but it is very much an abuse of the mechanism and you can't expect good performance. Properly normalizing your data is exactly the sort of thing Power Query is intended to do, before you make an SSAS model out of it.

Answer (score 0):

Like @Jeroen Mostert suggests, you *can* do this by abusing the [PATHCONTAINS](https://dax.guide/pathcontains/) function like this:

```
FilteredTable2 =
VAR CurrKey = SELECTEDVALUE ( Table1[ValueKey] )   
VAR PathFromKey = SUBSTITUTE ( CurrKey, ",", "|" ) /* Paths use | as separator. */
RETURN
    FILTER ( Table2, PATHCONTAINS ( PathFromKey, Table2[ValueKey] ) )
```

However, this is **not** best practice for relating tables. In general, you don't want multiple keys in a single fields.